# How to make autotools generated ./configure enforce availability of C11's _Generic?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, autotools, c11

I have an autotools project which requires a compiler which supports C11's `_Generic` feature.

Clang 2.3 and gcc 4.9 support this, but gcc 4.8.2 (supplied with Ubuntu 14.04LTS) doesn't.

(Confusingly gcc 4.8.2 supports `--std=c11`, but not the `_Generic` feature of that standard.)

Is there a macro for configure.ac to enforce the use of a `_Generic` compatible compiler?

Comment: What about requiring gcc >= 4.9 or clang >= 2.3?

Comment: @ouah how can I require particular compilers - should I use the PKG_CHECK_MODULES as I do for library dependencies?

Comment: Yes, basically `-std=c11` doesn't tell you much. Even new versions of clang still don't seem to implement all feature test macros for the optional parts. In particular they miss to define `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` if the C library doesn't have C11 thread support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in test for this, but I think you can easily do it using a `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`.  The manual explains all the details, but basically you would give it a test program using `_Generic` as an argument, and then make the failure case call `AC_MSG_ERROR`.

In some cases, though, I think it is better simply not to check for language features that you plan to use unconditionally.  You can just use them and let compilation fail.

Comment: Checking beforehand is kinder to the prospective user of your code who unwittingly tries to compile it, though. Especially if they're not up on their C11 and don't know what `_Generic` is.